# match set of variables in txt file using perl

Tags: regex, perl, variables, pattern-matching

I would like to match a set of variables in input file to my data file and return various fields.

input.txt

```
ENSG00000165322
ENSG00000170540
ENSG00000143153
ENSG00000213145
```

The data.txt file contains multiple fields separated by (i think) a semi colon (;). Here's an example:

```
chr10   gencodeV7   gene    32094365    32217742    0.714042    -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000165322.12"; transcript_ids "ENST00000311380.4,ENST00000375250.5,ENST00000492028.1,ENST00000497085.1,ENST00000493008.1,ENST00000344936.2,ENST00000396144.4,ENST00000375245.4,ENST00000477117.1,ENST00000497103.1,ENST00000454919.1,"; RPKM1 "7.54177"; RPKM2 "9.47656"; iIDR "0.000";
chr16   gencodeV7   gene    18802991    18812917    7.333434    -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000170540.7"; transcript_ids "ENST00000304414.6,ENST00000545430.1,ENST00000546206.1,"; RPKM1 "84.0696"; RPKM2 "90.714"; iIDR "0.000";
```

I want to match each variable in input.txt with the data file and print out the matched term with the RPKM1, it's associated value in double quotation marks, and the RPKM2 value with it's corresponding value so that it looks like this and where there isn't a match to print out a N/A

```
ENSG00000165322 7.54177 9.47656
ENSG00000170540 84.0696 90.714
ENSG00000143153 73.2162 85.090
ENSG00000213145 N/A N/A
```

I can do this with awk using this script:

```
exec < input.txt
while read line
            do
            set $line
                   rpkm=`grep $1 data.txt  | cut -f9| cut -d";" -f 3-4 | sed -e 's/;/\t/g'`
                   echo $line $rpkm >> output.txt

        done
```

but I am trying to learn perl and after hours of searching, I've tried this one but I don't know how to get the output.

```
  use strict; 
  use warnings;
    my $input_txt = "input.txt" ;
    my $raw_data = "data.txt" ;
    if ($input_txt =~ $raw_data) ;
close $input
```

If you have any suggestions and explanations, that would be wonderful.

Comment: we can call this a variable ? 
RPKM2 "9.47656"

Comment: The variables are the input.txt such as ENSG00000165322 etc. I want to find the variable from input.txt in the data.txt file and print it out with it's corresponding RPKM1 and RPKM2 values. Hope this helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My perl skills are a little bit rusty, but I put this together for you.  I tested it with the snippets of data files that you provided in your question, and it works (except that the data example you provided did not provide a line for ENSG00000143153, and so the output would show N/A).

Not sure if your gene_id includes or excludes what's after the dot.  In your example, it seems to exclude, so that is what I have done.  (There is a commented out regex you can use in case I assumed incorrectly).

I tried to put enough comments in the perl code so that you can understand what it is that I'm doing along the way.

Hope this helps you out!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_file = 'input.txt';
my $data_file = 'data.txt';

# Read input file into array of variables
my @input_vars;
open my $input_file_handle, '<', $input_file or die $!;
while (<$input_file_handle>) {
  chomp $_;
  push @input_vars, $_;
}
close $input_file_handle;

# Read data file into array of data lines
my @data_lines;
open my $data_file_handle, '<', $data_file or die $!;
while (<$data_file_handle>) {
  chomp $_;
  push @data_lines, $_;
}
close $data_file_handle;

# Pare down data lines because we only care about gene_id, RPKM1, and RPKM2
# Create 2 associative arrays which store RPKM1 and RPKM2 values based on the gene_id as the key
my %rpkm1s;
my %rpkm2s;
foreach (@data_lines) {
  # If the gene id should exclude everything after the dot, as in your example.
  my $regex = 'gene_id(?:[ ]*)"(\w+)(?:\.\d+)?"(?:.*)RPKM1(?:[ ]*)"([0-9\.]+)"(?:.*)RPKM2(?:[ ]*)"([0-9\.]+)"';

  # If the gene id includes the dot and what's after it.
  # my $regex = 'gene_id(?:[ ]*)"(\w+\.\d+)"(?:.*)RPKM1(?:[ ]*)"([0-9\.]+)"(?:.*)RPKM2(?:[ ]*)"([0-9\.]+)"';

  while ($_ =~ m/$regex/g) {
    # $1 is gene_id, $2 is RPKM1, and $3 is RPKM2
    # Set RPKM1 value in array based on gene_id as the key
    $rpkm1s{$1} = $2;
    # Set RPKM2 value in array based on gene_id as the key
    $rpkm2s{$1} = $3;
  }
}

# Verify that I have gene_ids mapped to RPKM1 and RPKM2 values
#  while ((my $gene_id, my $rpkm1) = each(%rpkm1s)) {
#    print "GENE ID: $gene_id\n";
#    print "\tRPKM1: $rpkm1\n";
#    print "\tRPKM2: $rpkm2s{$gene_id}\n";
#    print "\n";
#  }

# Iterate through input variables, search for values in %rpkm1s and %rpkm2s
foreach (@input_vars) {
  print "$_ ";
  if (exists $rpkm1s{$_}) {
    print "$rpkm1s{$_} ";
  }
  else {
    print "N/A ";
  }

  if (exists $rpkm2s{$_}) {
    print "$rpkm2s{$_} ";
  }
  else {
    print "N/A ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Regex that matchs your variable:

```
([a-z]{1}[A-Z]{3} "[0-9]\.[0-9]{3}")
```

I'm not familiar with PERL but this Regex will return a group of variables you can iterate on them